# Is there any Laplace transform whose ROC contain a pole?

Tags: laplace-transform

While I was reading "Signals& Systems" by Oppenheim, I read that "For rational Laplace transforms,  the ROC does not contain any poles". So, I was wondering is there any non-rational Laplace transforms that contain poles.
[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2):

The region of convergence is defined as the region that does not contain any points where the integral is divergent. A pole is a point where the integral is divergent by definition. Thus, the region of convergence cannot contain any poles by definition.